# Open type font collections are causing errors with PdfPrintingCore "Font has no usable platform or encoding ID. It cannot be used with PDFEdit."

Tags: c#, windows, fonts, pdf-generation, .net-6.0

When printing any text in font type Cambria (or another .ttc font type) on Windows I get the following error message:
Font has no usable platform or encoding ID. It cannot be used with PDFEdit.

1. What should I do differently with printing to change this?
   With the NuGet package PdfPrintingCore. The website is pdfprinting.net
2. The specific line of code that throws the exception is on creating an XFont:

var pdfFont = new XFont("Cambria", 10, XFontStyle.Regular, XPdfFontOptions.UnicodeDefault);

3. I've tried to create the XPdfFontOptions to have embed always:

   var options = new XPdfFontOptions(XPdfFontOptions.UnicodeDefault, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
4. Hoping the font can be used when it's embedded. But this constructor has been deprecated and it cannot be compiled anymore. There's no alternative provided in the [documentation](https://www.pdfprinting.net/reference/html/8917328e-975b-de11-f7a9-3fe6fb438972.htm).
5. I've tried converting the .ttc to a .ttf file with a [website](https://transfonter.org/ttc-unpack). Since the c stands for collection, it should be possible to unpack the fonts into their separate files. This produces a Cambria-01.ttf and a CambriaMath-02.ttf file. Using them instead causes the same error.

Steps taken to implement the extraction option: Copy the font to a regular folder (the fonts folder behaves differently), which results in several files, extracting the ttc, renaming the extracted files to remove the enumeration, copy them back (the additional files and the extracted files), Windows displays 'installing font' popup, I can still use the font in Word.

Comment: This is the classic error with this package, as with many others which are all based on the same original component (PDFSharp https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp). It just doesn't support font families stored in a .ttc files which are as you found out collection files (you'll get the issue with "MingLiu-Extb" family name, stored in Mingliub.ttc file). Splitting the .ttc into multiple .ttf will not change the problem since it lies into the library code, in fact someone else got this error ... https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/blob/master/src/PdfSharp/Fonts.OpenType/OpenTypeFontTables.cs#L173

Comment: There may be a workaround though, can you test that program based on a custom `IFontResolver`, using the extracted .ttf files: https://pastebin.com/raw/g0ZsR2rn see if you really can work with this font?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yea, they don't support these fonts, very strange. Do you know a different modern PDF writing package that does support them? We upgraded from iTextSharp which did support these fonts.

Comment: Not particularly, but I would try all serious component vendors: syncfusion, aspose, gembox, devexpress, telerik, etc. But have you tried my workaround code? It should be enough to make it work.

Comment: @SimonMourier when using your code,  it fails when adding the resolver to the GlobalFontSettings:  "Must not change font resolver after is was once used."  Any idea how to overcome this issue?

Comment: @Romias - you should ask another question